# Converting string taken from file to datetime

Tags: c#

Language is C#

Hi,

I'm trying to make an employee time calculator.  I created 3 buttons, IN, OUT and READ. In and OUT, when pressed, saves the system time to a file.

> Format saved in file is: OUT  3/9/2017 3:20:55 PM

I can also read the values but when try to convert it in datetime it throws exception. 
Can anyone guide how can I calculate the difference of two values taken from file.

Issue is in button 3

```
         private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int a = 0;
        string path = @"C:\Users\Public\WriteLines.txt";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
             string line;
             string[] lines= new String[500]; 
            // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
            // the file is reached.
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                lines[a] = line;
                a++;
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                Console.WriteLine(a);
     //  DateTime date3 = DateTime.Parse(lines[1]);
      //         DateTime date4 = DateTime.Parse(lines[2]);
       //        DateTime date4 = DateTime.ParseExact(lines[2], "d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", null);

                 TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Parse(lines[1]) - DateTime.Parse(lines[2]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I dont want to read all that junk.  Please edit your question to just the relevant code.

Comment: We don't need all this information and code, we just need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to tell us what exception you are getting, and we need the strings you are feeding into `DateTime.Parse`. Your entire post is probably: "Why does `TimeSpan difference = DateTime.Parse("Format: OUT 3/9/2017 3:20:55 PM") - DateTime.Parse("Format: OUT 3/9/2017 3:20:55 PM");` throw a FormatException?"

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the earlier comments about too much info.
Having said that, it looks like your string contains "IN" or "OUT". DateTime.Parse() can't deal with that so parse those out so you have only the datetime portion of the string to feed to DateTime.Parse().

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by using

> TimeSpan difference = Convert.ToDateTime(lines[a]) -
>   Convert.ToDateTime(lines[a-1]);